# python-instagram can create new account in Instagram?

Tags: python, api, instagram, registration

I am talking about this library
https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

is that possible to get registered there with the help of Python library?

so we can create new accounts in Instagram with out using any Android/Ios device or any Simulator

looking for the answer
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: creating Instagram user account without any smartphone devices or simulator

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't [any endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) that lets you create a user, I don't think that a wrapper library does

Comment: You are right @qdii . I've fixed the grammar error

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium package for Instagram scraping without API.